# Subcaption: horizontal alignment of images

Tags: subcaption

I currently want to depicting how an algorithm is working. The algorithm is using three different steps, which are repeatedly called.

So I want a result like this:

[image: Whised result]

But I currently only get

[image: Current]

My source:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

Test
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I already had the idea to add two dummy images to archive my wished result

```
\subcaptionbox{}{
    \phantomcaption
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[opacity=0] (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

But using of phantomcaption only result in changed caption (always "a" instead of "e" and "f", whereas I expected a removed caption)

Comment: Remove `\centering`.

Comment: I don't want remove \centering, because left and right spacing should be same.

Comment: Perhaps \hfill\mbox{}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use two `\phantom` images:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

Test
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    \subcaptionbox{}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    \subcaptionbox{}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }\par
    \subcaptionbox{}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
        \phantom{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \phantom{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use a tabular:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

Test
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{ }l@{ }l@{}}
\subcaptionbox{}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
&
\subcaptionbox{}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
&
\subcaptionbox{}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\\
\subcaptionbox{}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note the protection against spurious spaces given by `%` at the end of some lines.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

If you want the subfigure to take the full text width, don't use `\centering` and put `\hfill` between each subfigure

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

Test
\begin{figure}[h]
    %\centering
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \hfill
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \hfill
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    } \\
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: visu]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\DeclareFloatVCode{myrowsep}{\vskip 2.5ex}

%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
Test
\begin{figure}[h]
\floatsetup{justification =centering, rowpostcode=myrowsep}
\ffigbox{
\begin{subfloatrow}[3]
\ffigbox{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
}{\caption{}\label{fig-a}}
\ffigbox{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
}{\caption{}\label{fig-b}}
\ffigbox{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
}{\caption{}\label{fig-c}}
\end{subfloatrow}
\begin{subfloatrow}[3]
\ffigbox{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
}{\caption{}\label{fig-d}}
\hspace*{0.667\linewidth}
\end{subfloatrow}
}
{\caption{Four images}\label{4im}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]